# How to use a variable to pass a crop string argument to cpdf in bash

Tags: string, bash, variables

This question is about how, in bash, one can (and cannot) pass a string—**which is contained in a bash variable**—as an argument to a binary executable. I am using a particular binary executable, but the question is broader, because we may want to pass string arguments to all kinds of binary executables.

I understand that the behavior described below may turn out to be very special to the binary executable I am calling. But I suspect that what I am describing is a reflection of something basic in how bash works, in which case it could be of interest to a border range of people.

**Background**

This question arose in the course of me writing a bash script that uses `cpdf` [(link)](https://community.coherentpdf.com/), which is a binary executable. The program `cpdf` is open source; the source code (in OCaml) is available [here](https://github.com/johnwhitington/cpdf-source).

**Basic usage of the binary executable in question**

Suppose, in a bash terminal, the working directory contains a one-page pdf file called `in.pdf`.

Then the following command produces a pdf file called `out.pdf` containing a cropped window from `in.pdf`:

```
cpdf -crop "10pt 10pt 200pt 500pt" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

The size of the crop is specified by the string `"10pt 10pt 200pt 500pt"` (For completeness: if the crop window has its lower-left corner at (x1,y1) and upper-right corner ar (x2,y2), then the string format is x1 y1 x2 y2—plus the units, all enclosed in quote marks.)

**Using a variable to pass the crop string**

The following will work:

```
cropstring="10pt 10pt 200pt 500pt"
cpdf -crop "$cropstring"  $filein -o out1.pdf
```

But the following will not:

```
cropstring="\"10pt 10pt 200pt 500pt\""
cpdf -crop $cropstring  $filein -o out2.pdf
```

If you execute the latter, it returns the error message

```
Bad rectangle specification "10pt
```

The difference is that in the first case, the enclosing quote marks are not part of the string which is contained in the variable `cropstring`, while in the second case, they are part of it.

**Questions**

Is this behavior likely to be very specific to `cpdf`, or is it reflective of some general properties of bash? If the latter, then two more questions: why doesn't the second way work? Is there a way to define the variable `cropstring` so that the second way (meaning, all required quote marks are somehow included in the content of the variable) does work?

Comment: `cpdf` is irrelevant. Word splitting is performed on `$cropstring`, but not on `"$cropstring"`. Compare `printf "<%s> " $cropstring; echo` and `printf "<%s> " "$cropstring"; echo`, after the assignment `cropstring="\"10pt 10pt 200pt 500pt\""`. Read [Word Splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) for more information.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thank you for this comment and the link. I think I was (and perhaps still am) confused by the distinction between the initial splitting into tokens (done before any expansions, according to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)) and 'word splitting' (done after variable expansion, according to the order of precedence mentioned in the article you linked). These two splitting operations seem (at least superficially) very similar, almost like there is an initial word splitting before any expansions. Is that a wrong way to think about it?

Comment: *Word*s resulting from tokenization are semantically categorized before any expansion (or the like) is performed. Word expansions and other similar operations can't change the meaning of a word (e.g: `a='>file'; echo $a` prints `>file`, it doesn't write a blank line to `file`). That is the difference you seem to be missing.

Comment: After parameter expansion and word splitting, the quote characters *that resulted from the parameter expansion* are considered literal characters and are not subject to quote removal by `bash`. For example, after the assignment `var='"Hello world"'`, `$var` (without quotes) expands to two words: `"Hello` and `world"`. No rescanning for quote characters (`"`s here) resulted from the expansion is performed; quote characters lose their special meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that `cpdf` is not a string interpreter like `echo` or `printf` and so on. In your case `cpdf` doesn't know how to interpret your escaped string and when you pass this "so called" variable (cropstring) to cpdf binary you actually tell to bash like this: **pass to cpdf script this argument in which you close double-quote and after** `\"10pt` **you have a space which means cpdf jump to next argument (input file) and leave away this part of string** `10pt 200pt 500pt\"` **(that means that your script will take 10pt as a single argument and that is unfortunate because your binary script expect other 3 arguments)**. This is why your binary raise an error because it cannot crop a window having just one argument `10pt`. It expects yet 3 arguments **in a string**.

This is how your binary script will exit (with an error) and tell you that there is a `Bad rectangle specification "10pt.`

The arguments that you pass to cpdf are good in first example but in the second example are wrong. I described earlier how bash interpret parameters. In the first example your binary script treat `cropstring` as a string variable and in the second example it will pass only the first argument which is `10pt`.

To respond to your answer, it is the way bash interpret strings and your script and not a problem of cpdf binary.

The line in which you write:
`cropstring="\"10pt 10pt 200pt 500pt\""`
can be interpreted well only by a text interpreter (you can play writing `echo -e $cropstring`) but **NEVER in bash command line**. When you pass your variable as an argument to some bash script, bash see your variable like `cpdf -crop ""10pt`. That's all because the rest of the string will be seen as file.in argument. The error occurs because your string parameter asked by crop argument is just 10pt and thus, the binary doesn't know how to crop that window.